# Javascript - How deeply can a variable retain its value?

Tags: javascript, callback, google-chrome-extension

Noob question here. Please see code below.
Where can I read more on this? I mean, `this_variable` gets **100**. All subsequently defined functions seem to be able to access this variable and get it's value, but I wonder how deep does this work? I'm working on a Chrome extension and the damn thing only works with callbacks; I need to be able to access stuff within a pretty deeply nested callback and I need to be sure that what I write is reliable and will remain consistent.

```
(function(){

    this_variable = 100;

    (function(){
        (function(){
            (function(){
                (function(){
                    (function(){

                        tadaaa = this_variable;
                        console.log(tadaaa); // sais 100                

                    }());
                }());
            }());
        }());
    }());
}());
```

Comment: Why would there be a limit? What purpose would it serve?

Comment: If it happens that `tadaaa` is somehow not set properly then it means that your computer is going to reboot in a second ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As deeply as you want. The name for the concept is [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/5056) and it is the **most** important concept when programming advanced javascript.

Comment: Yes, that's what they were called, closures. Thanks, I'll dig.

Answer (score 6):

There is no limit.  Though if you're nested deeply enough to worry about a limit, I would question the overall design.

Comment: Though I wouldn't *necessarily* discourage deep nesting. That's how functional programming works after all.

Comment: Most of the chrome.* API is comprised of asynchronous functions. How else would I change the overall design? Working with the global scope?

Comment: That's why I only said "question" the design.  I can't see it so I don't know, it may be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

As long as a variable is 'in scope' it can be accessed (presuming it's not hidden). You can nest as much as you like. See [here for scoping and closure reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) from MDN.

Answer (score 1):

As far as you goes..

It might be slower at some point, but should still be accessible all the way through your callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses function scoping.  The rule is if a variable is set within the top level function, then all of the nested functions within the top level function have access to that variable.  If a variable is declared within a nested function, then the top level function(s) will not have access to that variable.

```
//Immediately invoked function that scopes jQuery and outside code cannot access
$(function() {
    //top-level function
    function test() {
        var a = true;
        //nested function
        function nestedTesting() {
            //The nested function has access to a
            console.log(a);
            var b = false;
        }
        nestedTesting();
        //The top level function does not have access to b
        console.log(b);
    }
    test();
});
```

**Expected Result:**

1. true
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined